# Are 'probably' and 'actually' mutually exclusive?

Tags: oxymoron

I had an argument with my acquaintances:

```
[discussing the same translations of the phrase to various languages]

xxx: the German sentence is wrong, for what it's worth
yyy: the French one is too
yyy: they probably all are, actually
me:  yyy, congratulations. The last sentence, that you wrote is an oxymoron
xxx: how's that an oxymoron?
yyy: probably … actually? Arguably, the actual fact is that it is likely they all are wrong

[this is followed by an argument]
```

To tell the truth, none of us is a native English speaker, but my knowledge of the language is worst out of the three people.

So, I have a question. Is 'they probably all are, actually' sentence an oxymoron or not?

Comment: Good thing you're not native English speakers, or you would have said "literally" and we'd be having a whole 'nother discussion.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? What kind of discussion are you implying?

Comment: I'm just joking about the tendency of people (teenage American girls, mostly) to use the word "literally" when they are trying to emphasize a point. It would be even more out of place than "actually" is in your example.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for explanation. :)

Comment: **"Oh my God! He's dead!"**. **"No - he's probably just been knocked out, actually."** I don't see a problem with the logic there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Actually* is used to add emphasis to the truth of what you are saying, while *probably* is used to say that something is likely to happen. They can certainly be used together with no contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Actually could be replaced by “as a matter of fact”.

So “they probably all are, as a matter of fact”.

However, you are unsure that they are all wrong and so it can't be a matter of fact.

This is where the confusion lies for me.

Comment: Actually, I think in the usage we're talking about here, the word *actually* can probably be more accurately expanded to *as a matter of fact* **which you may well be unaware of**. I don't see anything unquestionably oxymoronic in using this in the same statement as "probably".

Answer (score 1):

An **oxymoron** is a figure of speech containing contradictory terms, such as "living dead". You have not committed an oxymoron. Perhaps the word your friend was looking for is **redundancy**.

Comment: It's 'me' who said “oxymoron”, and I think he meant it as such. He's just asking if that's true or not. (This comment is meant as a downvote, only I can't yet ^_^)